# AWS plugin on Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to use Jenkins as a build server hosted on aws. For that I have an EC2 instance with Jenkins up and running. I installed the AWS EC2 plugin but when I try to configure it (by going to jenkins -> configure system -> add cloud -> aws) I get the following error:
Stack trace

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:
```

I can't even fill in the AWS credentials. 
Anybody have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

some people have worked around this error by not ticking the "IAM Role" checkbox when configuring AWS.

see open jenkins issue: [S3 plugin - Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36430)

see also stackoverflow question: [Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain - Jenkins & AWS codepipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40730024/6090676)